# Best Regex for my Purpose

Tags: c#, regex

All, I have the following list of strings

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() 
{ 
    "Japanese (Japan) (ja-jp)",
    "Scottish Gaelic (United Kingdom) (gd-gb)", 
    "German (Germany) (de-DE)", 
    "Amharic (Ethiopia) (am-et)"
};
```

I want to get the following strings from this list:

```
ja-jp
gd-gb
de-DE 
am-et
```

I am currently using groups and the `Regex`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.*)\s*(\(.*\))\s*(\(.*\))");
```

Can someone offer a better `Regex`?

Comment: bet·ter  

/ˈbetər/



Adjective


Of a more excellent or effective type or quality: "hoping for better weather"; "I'm better at algebra than Alice". 
 
 

Adverb


More excellently or effectively: "Johnny could do better if he tried"; "instruments are generally better made these days". 
 
 

Noun


The better one; that which is better: "the Natural History Museum book is by far the better of the two"; "a change for the better".

Comment: lol. Faster? More robust? More flexible?

Comment: @Killercam: I had to struggle not to upvote that comment just for its snark value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this to have the whole pattern as result:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?>[^()]+)(?=\)$)");
```

or simply:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^()]+(?=\)$)");
```

Answer (score 5):

If your codes will always be in that format, you can use substring extraction instead of regex:

```
var codes = list.Select(l => l.Substring(l.Length - 6, 5)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
@"^.*\(([\w\-]+)\)$"
```

It is shorter and only captures the relevant text.

Comment: No, there weren't too many brackets. It didn't match the dash (`-`) though. It does now.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result =  list.Select(s=>s.Split('(').Last().TrimEnd(')')).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*\((.+)\)$");

foreach (string item in list)
{
    string result = regex.Match(item).Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@"(?<=[(])[a-zA-Z]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{2}(?=[)])"` would match only the `xx-xx` in parentheses.  Meaning that `thatPattern.Match(input).Value` would be equal to it, without having to fart around with capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = list.Select(s => Regex.Match(s, @"\((\w+\-\w+)\)").Groups[1].Value)
                 .ToList();
```